# Add a button on top (floating) of UISplitView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

My app contains only one `UISplitViewController`. Now I want to add a floating button on top of the window. But it is not possible to use the storyboard to drag a button to the `UITableViewController` of the master view, because by default, the master view contains only a `UITableView`.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding Split View Controller inside a Container View?

Comment: By default, there is only a table view. Do you suggest to nest it in a container?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a new View controller before your split view controller. And in this new controller add the button on top and add the container view to fill the rest of the view.

[image: Storyboard]

Then create a segue from container view to Split View Controller by viewDidLoad/embed

[image]

That's all!

[image]